# How can I calculate aggregate standard deviation when some sample size = 1?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I'm developing a web performance analytics tool. I don't want to store every data point, so I plan to compile the averages and standard deviations of page load times every hour, and then compile *those* statistics daily.

Here's an example in SQL:

```
insert into #Hits (TimeCreated, LoadTime)
values
    (getdate(), 785),
    (getdate(), 1239),
    (getdate(), 992),
    (dateadd(hour, 1, getdate()), 948),
    (dateadd(hour, 1, getdate()), 902),
    (dateadd(hour, 2, getdate()), 1002)
```

The hourly compilation of these data points looks like this:

```
2017-11-11 09:00:00     3   1005    227
2017-11-11 10:00:00     2   925     32
2017-11-11 11:00:00     1   1002    NULL
```

The last row makes sense, because [standard deviation is undefined when the sample size = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023878/standard-deviation-of-one-element).

So **how do I account for that single data point** in an aggregate standard deviation which, according to this equation from Wikipedia, relies on standard deviations of the sets being aggregated?

[image: Aggregate standard deviation]

Comment: You might do better deleting this question here and asking instead at cross validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the same formula, but with the following term replaced by the square of the single observation when $N_{X_i}=1$:

$$\left[(N_{X_i} - 1) \sigma_{X_i}^2 + N_{X_i} \mu_{X_i}^2\right].$$

This term is just calculating the sum of squared observations in the $i$th sample, which is just the single squared observation when $N_{X_i}=1$, even though the $i$th *sample* variance $\sigma_{X_i}^2$ (defined using denominator $N_{X_i} - 1$) is undefined in that case.

---

To see what's going on here, just write out the definition of the sample variance for an overall sample-set $X$ that's the union of disjoint sample-sets $X_1,X_2,...$:

$$\begin{align}\sigma_X^2 &=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\sum_{x\in X}(x-\mu_X)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\sum_{x\in X}\left(x^2-2\,x\,N_X+\mu_X^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\left(\sum_{x\in X}x^2-2\,\sum_{x\in X}x\,N_X+\sum_{x\in X}\mu_X^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\left(\sum_{x\in X}x^2-2\,N_X\mu_X\,N_X+N_X\mu_X^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\left(\sum_{x\in X}x^2-N_X\mu_X^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N_X-1}\left(\sum_i\color{blue}{\sum_{x\in X_i}x^2}-N_X\mu_X^2\right).\\
\end{align}$$

Now by definition, *when $N_{X_i}>1$*,
$$\sigma_{X_i}^2 =\frac{1}{N_{X_i}-1}\sum_{x\in X_i}\left(x-\mu_{X_i}\right)^2=\frac{1}{N_{X_i}-1}\left(\sum_{x\in X_i}x^2-N_{X_i}\mu_{X_i}^2 \right).$$
Hence, by rearranging, we have, *when $N_{X_i}>1$*,
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{x\in X_i}x^2} = (N_{X_i}-1)\sigma_{X_i}^2+N_{X_i}\mu_{X_i}^2.
$$
On the other hand, when $N_{X_i}=1$ (i.e. when $X_i=\{x_i\}$, say) we have simply
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{x\in X_i}x^2} = x_i^2.$$
So, it's just a matter of using the correct formula for the sum of squared observations in the $i$th sample. For convenience, we can write the final result as follows:

$$\sigma_X^2 = \frac{1}{N_X-1}\left(\sum_i\,SS_i-N_X\mu_X^2\right)\tag{1}
$$ 
where $SS_i=\sum_{x\in X_i}x^2$ is the sum-of-squares for the $i$th sample: $$SS_i = 
\begin{cases} 
(N_{X_i}-1)\sigma_{X_i}^2+N_{X_i}\mu_{X_i}^2,  & \text{if }N_{X_i}>1\\
x_i^2, & \text{if }N_{X_i}=1, X_i=\{x_i\} \tag{2}
\end{cases} 
$$

**NB**: Equivalently, we could simply *define* the quantity

$$\sigma_{X_i}^2=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{N_{X_i}-1}\sum_{x\in X_i}\left(x-\mu_{X_i}\right)^2 & \text{if }N_{X_i}>1\\
0 & \text{if }N_{X_i}=1
\end{cases}$$
and use the following in (1):
$$SS_i = (N_{X_i}-1)\sigma_{X_i}^2+N_{X_i}\mu_{X_i}^2\text{ if }N_{X_i}\ge 1.\tag{2'}$$

In other words, you could simply replace the `NULL` by `0`, and use that directly in your original formula.

Comment: So there's actually no need to change the equation, right? As long as the standard deviation of the sample with N=1 is non-null, the first part of that sum will be zero (because [N-1]*stddev=0).

Comment: (I can always wrap the standard deviation to turn nulls into zeros.)

Comment: @mac9416 - Yes, that's right.